# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError while splitting a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to check if a string is JSON or not. If a string is not JSON string, I am trying to split the string (based on delim `":"`). But it is throwing `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError`. I must be doing some silly mistake. But unable to figure out the issue.

Below is the simple program.

```
import json

str = "SIP/2.0 200"
try:
    json.loads(str)
except ValueError as err:
    substr = str.split((':', 1))
```

Below is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: must be str or None, not tuple
```

If I just print the string without splitting, it is working fine as below.

```
import json

str = "SIP/2.0 200"
try:
    json.loads(str)
except ValueError as err:
    print(str)
    print(type(str))
```

**O/P:**

```
SIP/2.0 200
<class 'str'>
```

Not sure why I am getting this error. I might be doing some simple mistake. But unable to figure out the issue. Can anyone please help me to understand why splitting is failing.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It looks like the JOSNDecodeError is not from the code you entered but from a previous version when it was not wrapped in the `try` block. Can you verify that the code you pasted still raises the exception? The error is pointing to line 4 so it might be useful to change it to `except Exception` as a catch all  so you can verify that you are excepting the right error type

Comment: @joshmeranda: The error  is from the code I entered only. I haven't used any other code. I tried from command line also and same error.

Comment: This is a typo, you have an extra set of parentheses in `str.split((':', 1))` it should be `str.split(':', 1)`. The extra parentheses make a tuple which is then passed to `split` as a single argument

Comment: Using python3 I could reproduce (not sure why this machine had python 2 as the default). @PatrickHaugh is right, just remove the unnecessary parantheses